# How to automatically set the div container adaptively towards the content length?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make the div container can automatically resize its div-size (height) along side with the content, instead of going out of the area when the text is more than container area. Can anyone help me out to fix this instead of editing up the css for div-container? When I tried to change the div-size even it fits up the content, but while it is more than the div-area, I have to edit it manually again through CSS code.

Is it possibly to make it automatically? or maybe using JavaScript function?

Comment: Could you make a js-fiddle with your code so someone can see what you're seeing?

Comment: You should share you code , what you have tried so far ..

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
div#div_id{
     height : auto;
     min-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Set your div height to `auto`. It will take height automatically as per your contents.

Comment: Which is the default behavior, so you might just want to remove your height rules for this div.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you want is just what a div - or other so-called block-level-element - naturally does unless you give it a defined height. So just remove any fixed heights you apply to the container and you're done.

In case you want your div to be of a certain minimum/maximum height, use min-height/max-height instead of height for that.